# How to allow "." in @Html.Label() method

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want show label as "No. Of Student" using `@Html.Label("No. of Student",new{@id="noOfStudent"})`.

While executing this statement output is like:
`of Student`

The part `No.` is skipped and this is due to `.` character.

How can I let `No.` be part of the output, too?

Comment: `@Html.Label("yourPropertyName", "No. of Student")` (but not clear why your adding an `id` attribute) or better `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.yourProperty)` and decorate your property with the `Display(Name = "No. of Student")]` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Why you didn't use a strong tipization?
In your **.cshtml** add at start a using reference to your model (the one you passed to the **View**):

```
@model Namespace.whateveryouplacedtheclassofyourmodel
```

Now, you can use the model binding in your **View** like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.property)
```

Then, you can add custom parameters in your model **class** file using metadata attributes, in this case place this piece of code above the property you wanna apply (**you need to add an using to the class**):

```
[Display(Name = "No. of Student")]
```